# Why does my for loop only return first value in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, for-loop, jtable

So I'm using this for loop to go through the values held in the first column. Then the if statement deletes the row if the value entered by the user is equal to the the value held in String hold. I am able to delete the first row but can not delete any row after that. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

```
 private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   //adds a row to table
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{name, "JohnSMith@example.com", "03-16/05-17"});

}                                         

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // deletes row from table
    String dName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

   int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();

   for(int i = 0; i <= rows;i++){
        String hold = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        if(hold.equals(dName)){
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
        break;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

1. You have a `break;` in your for loop that is probably misplaced. Did you intend that to be part of the `if(hold.equals(name)){}` block?
2. You are deleting rows from the *model* using a *view index*. [`JTable.getRowCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount%28%29) returns the number of rows in the view, not the model. The number of rows in the view can differ from the number of rows in the model due to filtering.

   You then iterate the rows using an index, look up values in the view to then delete from the model. That will fail when you have sorting in your JTable.

   You need to convert view indices to model indices and vice versa using the [`JTable.convertRowIndexToView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29) and [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29).

   Same deal for columns, columns can be rearranged by the user by dragging them to a different position. The call to `jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0)` will give you the value in the first column in the **view**, not the **model**. Look into [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29) and [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29).
3. As these rows are deleted, the number of rows in the model changes of course, so the check with `i<rows` will lead to array out of index exceptions.

---

Two alternative ways to delete matching rows (in order of my preference):

1. Loop the model with a `for(int i=0;i!=model.getRowCount();++i)`. Look up the value using [`model.getValueAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29). Delete the row with [`model.removeRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow%28int%29), afterwards decrement your loop variable (eg `model.removeRow(i--);`).
2. Iterate the model's [`dataVector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector%28%29) to find the rows to delete, and delete them using [`Iterator.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29). After your loop, call [`fireTableChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableChanged%28javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent%29) on your model.

Comment: hmmm DefaultTableModel has all notifiers implemented and correctly, please to remove - call fireTableChanged on your model. (it can be nonsense :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, but the last "alternative" is to directly use/modify the underlying `dataVector` of the `DefaultTableModel` (a `Vector<Vector<Object>>`). That would require firing that method. I put that second, the first alternative is preferred I guess. I'm always grunting that the `DefaultTableModel` has no way to iterate the underlying data vector using an `Iterator`.

Comment: I think that DefaultTableModel.removeRow(index); is removing this row without the needs to call the duplicate methods, DataVector is directly accesible from  DefaultTableModel without casting to TableModel

Comment: @mKorbel The two alternatives are completely distinct ways to approach deleting rows. Using the first alternative doesn't require `fireXXXChanged` methods as you correctly point out. I've updated the answer to show more clearly that the two alternatives are distinct.